# path сделать адаптивным

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой `svg` в коде на фон, и он растягивается на всю страницу как положено, но `path` внутри него почему-то не заполняет весь экран:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 330">
  <path class="x-1" opacity="0.2" fill="#4C72A0" d="M0,0c300-1.128,155.667,307.332,500,330H0V0z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Как сделать `path` внутри `svg` на всю ширину и высоту экрана?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы понять, где находятся границы svg, добавляем бордюр в шапку svg файла

`style="border:1px solid red;"`  После настройки пропорций и размеров эта красная рамка будет не нужна, сотрите её.

Чтобы svg занял всё пространство контейнера добавляем внутри svg файла `width="100%"`, `height="100%"` и команду `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

```html
<style>
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 
}
</style>
<div class="bg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 330" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid red;" >
  <path class="x-1" opacity="0.2" fill="#4C72A0" d="M0,0c300-1.128,155.667,307.332,500,330H0V0z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, а прокрутка небольшая по обеим осям это из-за чего ?

Comment: @user3178479 очень долго объяснять, как svg позиционируется и масштабируется в этом конкретном примере. Уберите `width` `height` в стилях `body` и полоса прокрутки исчезнет

Comment: дошло, спасибо!

Comment: @user3178479 не за что:) Задавайте любые вопросы по svg, не стесняйтесь. Также можно спросить в чате по svg, если смогу на словах объяснить, то отвечу https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat